# android widget 4x2 full size photo prepare?

Tags: android, widget

I want to design widget about 4x2 cells size.

But I read the offical document ,

there are minWidget and minHeight individually setting in the AppWidgetProviderInfo metadata.

Now I want to set full size photo(not use 9 patch method) in 4x2 cells.

How to prepare the photo size in pixels and set in the widget layout width and height(dp)?

I had saw the minWidth and minHeight 4x2 is 250x110dp in document.

(http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html)

I set the value in the metadata(AppWidgetProviderInfo), and if I setting the size in the widget_layout width and height build in the 
cell phone. the widget is showing very small.

How to prepare the photo pixels in the 4x2 cells full size in the different folders, please?

Thank you very much.

My English is not good. so I express my meaning hardly. 
( I know the chinese)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the image to be full size you need to specify that in `XML`. In `XML` you can specify the height and width. Then you can say `adjustViewBounds` and set that to "true". Next you can tell the image how you want it positioned. For myself I prefer `scaleType` set to "centerCrop".

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/text"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/a_picture" />
```

Either way you can mess with the XML settings to get the image to adjust to your liking, this is just a sample to get you started

If your only doing widgets a 9 patch is recommended but you can simply place an image in your drawable hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, and xxhdpi folders. You can find the scaling ratios [**at this link**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)